# How to create multiple entries and output for create-react-app and keep them separated?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, electron, create-react-app

My use case is that I am using electron and would like to have multiple windows that can be loaded.  One will load initially, a node app, but will not be displayed to the user.  I am simply using it to run specific tasks.  The other window will be the UI client and this will be built in react.  I am using create-react-app.

Steps I’ve taken

- I have ejected.
- I have created multiple entry points.

Basically, I have followed discussion [here](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/1084)

The problem I am currently facing, is webpack is inserting my second bundled file into the orignal `index.html`

I would like both bundles to remain completely separate as the secondary bundle will be initiated by electron.

What do I need to modify in my webpack configuration to keep the bundles completely separate?

## Modifications Made

*webpack.config.dev.js*

Entry:

```
entry: {
  app: [
    require.resolve('./polyfills'),
    require.resolve('react-dev-utils/webpackHotDevClient'),
    paths.appIndexJs,
  ],
  secondary: [
    require.resolve('./polyfills'),
    require.resolve('react-dev-utils/webpackHotDevClient'),
    paths.secondaryIndexJs,
  ]
},


output: {
  pathinfo: true,
  filename: 'static/js/[name].bundle.js',
  chunkFilename: 'static/js/[name].chunk.js',
  publicPath: publicPath,
  devtoolModuleFilenameTemplate: info =>
  path.resolve(info.absoluteResourcePath).replace(/\\/g, '/'),
},
```

Additional `HtmlWebpackPlugin` in plugins

```
new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
  inject: true,
  chunks: ["secondary"],
  template: paths.secondaryHtml,
  filename: 'secondary.html',
}),
```

*paths.js*

- modified accordingly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is to simply add  `excludeChunks: ["secondary"],` to the original `HtmlWebpackPlugin` property.

#### In its totality:

```
 new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
  inject: true,
  template: paths.appHtml,
  excludeChunks: ["secondary"]
}),
new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
  inject: true,
  chunks: ["secondary"],
  template: paths.secondaryHtml,
  filename: 'secondary.html',
}),
```